# Alignments w/ CSS, and IE CSS Conditionals

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm building a pretty heavy J.Query website and, as always, it looks great in the modern browsers - but I am coming across all types of alignment issues in IE 6 & 7. More severely in IE 6. I'm working on building a conditional IE Style sheet for those browsers and am wondering - is there a way to align all divs with CSS? Can I permanently position everything to be, and stay center throughout all browsers and window sizes?

**Ultimately; any suggestions on fixing margin issues that occur in older IE's? Stuff that looks great in modern browsers and pushed off to the right and top in IE 6 & 7.** ..If the conditional is the inevitable route, what's a good way to start defining the parameters within?

Comment: FYI, if you haven't gotten it already... it's written as small j Query, not capital J dot Query. (That may also be why you can't tag your questions [j.query] for example.)

Answer (score 0):

are we talking horizontally or vertically?

Horizontally, the "margin:0px auto" should always center the div horizontally along the screen, so long as the width is set.  This works for all browsers IE6+ i believe.

There's a pretty good forum here : http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/8003.htm

Comment: Horizontally, sorry - awesome, thanks! I'm gonna plug it in & give it a try now.

Comment: This seemed to work in some cases, but in others I'm still trying to figure it out. I'm thinking possibly due to the amount of all types of j.Query and correlating css I have going on in the site, maybe some of these styles are being ignored or aren't rendering right. A good bit with Safari, but especially with IE 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your problem is that you have poorly written CSS.  Certainly, IE6 has plenty of issues, but if you're seeing problems in other modern browsers, then your problems are with your CSS, not standards conformance.

If I were you, i'd just ignore IE6.  It's down to less than 5% of the market (some surveys say as little as 2%).  Just let it die.

As RCNeil says, using margin centering works with everything.  If it's not working, then you have something else causing your problem and we can't possibly guess without seeing your page.

NOTE: in older versions of IE, if your document is being rendered in quirks mode, then you will have problems with auto margin.  Make sure your document renders in standards mode.